# Anyone know the name of a specific Urban-Fantasy tale with an online twist?

Tags: story-identification, novel, urban-fantasy

I've not been able to find what the book was called, I borrowed it from a library ages ago, and I want to reread it.

The problem is that I don't remember the name, though I'll share what plot detail I remember.

There's a website that has gotten sentience through means unknown to me, and a hacker infected the website with a virus. Because of this, the website created people to avenge or save itself.

Some people got sucked into the website, too, resulting in their arrival in a different world, a kind of fiefdom of sorts belonging to a larger supernatural world.

So, does anyone know what this novel was called?

Edit: Addition since I just remembered, the website was about literature, and had some kind of nature thematic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having had a flash of inspiration, I remembered the name of the website: "the Wordwood". Using that for my googling, I came upon *[Spirits in the Wire](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/186425.Spirits_in_the_Wires)* by Charles de Lint.

> At a popular Newford online research and library Web site called the Wordwood, a mysterious crash occurs. Everyone visiting the site at the moment of the crash vanishes from where they were sitting in front of their computers. Christy Ridding's girldfriend Saskia disappears right before his eyes, along with countless others.
>
> To rescue their missing friends, Christy and his companions must journey into Newford's otherworld, where the Wordwood, it transpires, has a physical presence of its own...

Thanks everyone who tried to answer the question, it's appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be one of the [Danger.Com](http://series.simonandschuster.com/danger-com) books? They all had plots similar to the one you describe: "Someone logged onto **the internet**, and now they're in terrible danger for some incredibly contrived reason!"

Comment: That doesn't sound like it. Sorry. The reasons weren't contrived, and it wasn't logging on to the Internet, it was someone actively trying to harm a website.

Answer (score 1):

It sort of sounds like [Space Demons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Demons), a novel channeling 80s anxiety about computer games. It was pretty good when I was 10, though.

The kids in that get sucked into a computer game, though. I don't recall if there was any explicit reference to computer networks, but this novel definitely predates the Web.

Comment: The novel I'm talking about was pretty clear about it being a website on the Internet, so that one must not be it either, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds a little bit like [Wyrm](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0553578081).

Comment: I'm afraid that's not the one, sorry.